# Падает скорость scipy.ndimage.imread

Tags: python, ubuntu, scipy

Приветствую. Python 2.7, Ubuntu16.04, hdd. В рамках решения задачи мне понадобилось обойти порядка 10 папок, каждая из которых содержит примерно 4500 маленьких картинок формата png. Каждую из картинок я обрабатываю следующим кодом на Python:

```
ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float)
```

В зависимости от некоторых обстоятельств, среднее время работы этого кода для одной картинки различается на три десятичных порядка. Вот что мне удалось заметить:

1) Если некоторая папка была обработана до какого-то момента, после чего программа была прервана, после запуска программы заново эта папка обрабатывается с хорошей скоростью до того же места, потом скорость снова падает.

2)После перезагрузки файлы и папки, на которых показывается хорошая скорость меняются непредсказуемым образом.

На всякий случай прилагаю весь небольшой [отрывок](http://pastebin.com/Lz0xNfq6) кода:

```
def load_letter(folder, min_num_images):
  image_files = os.listdir(folder)
  dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(image_files), image_size, image_size),
                         dtype=np.float32)
  print(folder)
  num_images = 0
  for image in image_files:
    image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)
    try:
      image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) -
                    pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
      if image_data.shape != (image_size, image_size):
        raise Exception('Unexpected image shape: %s' % str(image_data.shape))
      dataset[num_images, :, :] = image_data
      num_images = num_images + 1
      if(num_images % 400 == 0):
          print(str(num_images)+'\n')
    except IOError as e:
      print('Could not read:', image_file, ':', e, '- it\'s ok, skipping.')
  dataset = dataset[0:num_images, :, :]
  if num_images < min_num_images:
    raise Exception('Many fewer images than expected: %d < %d' %
                    (num_images, min_num_images))

  print('Full dataset tensor:', dataset.shape)
  print('Mean:', np.mean(dataset))
  print('Standard deviation:', np.std(dataset))
  return dataset

def maybe_pickle(data_folders, min_num_images_per_class, force=True):
  dataset_names = []
  data_folders.reverse()
  for folder in data_folders:
    print('\n\n\n\n\n\n'+folder+'\n\n\n\n\n\n')
    set_filename = folder + '.pickle'
    dataset_names.append(set_filename)
    if os.path.exists(set_filename) and not force:
      print('%s already present - Skipping pickling.' % set_filename)
    else:
      print('Pickling %s.' % set_filename)
      dataset = load_letter(folder, min_num_images_per_class)
      try:
        with open(set_filename, 'wb') as f:
          pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
      except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to save data to', set_filename, ':', e)

  return dataset_names

train_datasets = maybe_pickle(large_data, 45000)

test_datasets = maybe_pickle(small_data, 1800)
```

Comment: Может быть, дело в дисковом кеше?

Comment: Пришёл к тем же выводам, спасибо.